# What should be the better approach to find the minimum number of swaps required to sort the array in ascending order?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I am using below algorithm to solve this problem but it fails in major of the test cases. Please help me to find where i am making the mistake.

```
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    l=sorted(arr)
    count=0
    for num in l:
        i=arr.index(num)
        j=l.index(num)
        if(i!=j):
            count+=1
            arr[i],arr[j]=arr[j],arr[i]
            print(arr)
        else:
            continue
    return(count)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Which algorithm ?

Comment: I am simply comparing the indices of sorted and unsorted sequence and increment the counter if they don't match...It gives wrong number of swaps for major of the test cases.